# How to explode word using php

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

how to take a word in php or explode based on **luas Bangunan :xxx**
For example I have string

```
$string ="                 Kondisi Properti            : Bagus                    Dilengkapi Perabotan      : Unfurnished                    Sertifikat    : Lainnya                        Daya Listrik          : 2200 Watt                           Kamar Tidur         : 3/1                   Kamar Mandi      : 2/1                  **Luas Bangunan      : 92** m&sup2;                     Luas Tanah     : 126 m&sup2;                  Jumlah Lantai      : -<br>                 Kondisi Properti            : Bagus Sekali                       Dilengkapi Perabotan      : Unfurnished                    Sertifikat    : SHM - Sertifikat Hak Milik                         Daya Listrik          : 6600 Watt                       Saluran Telepon          : 1                        Garasi          : 3                             Kamar Tidur         : 4/1                   Kamar Mandi      : 3/1                  **Luas Bangunan      : 300** m&sup2;                     Luas Tanah     : 228 m&sup2;                 Jumlah Lantai      : 2.5                          ";
```

e.g. I want to take every "**Luas bangunan: xxx**"

Comment: using regex explode(':',$string); but it does not work thanks

Comment: you have to use regular expression. eg. use the function preg_match()  for your task... there are a lot of examples and howtos .. google for it and check the manual on php.net

Comment: hy donald123 thanks for your answer

Comment: `preg_match` doesn't split; `preg_split` splits.

Comment: Is the desired matched string always encased with `**`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a specific need. In your place i would explode the string by spaces $array = explode(' ',$string), explore the array with a foreach($array as $key=>$value), and test each value if it matches Luas with strpos( $value , 'Luas' ). So, when it matches 'Luas', you should test with an if condition that takes the next 3 indexes in the array, then concatenate and save these 4 words on this separated array.

Its like this:

```
$array = explode(' ',$string);
$match = 'Luas';
$matchesArray = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    //this var must word just like a temporary helper
    $target = '';
    //test each word
    if(strpos($value,$match) === true){

        //lets take the next word, 2 dots and the other word
        for($counter = 0;$counter <= 3;$counter++){
            //here we may construct our target phrase
            $nextWordsIndex = $key+$counter;
            $target.= $array[$nextWordsIndex].' ';
        }
        //but after the loop? Yes! we should take our target ready with 3 words
        $matchesArray[] = $target;
    }
}
//Now you should have a matchesArray with your wanted Information in each index.
```

Comment: Hy Matteus Barbosa, I've tried but did not work for me if you have any other suggestions for me anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: I have made some adjustments. It was not correct for real. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions with -> `preg_match_all` and  `preg_split` ,  i have put both because i don't undertand exactly what you want :)

```
<?php

$string =" Kondisi Properti : Bagus Dilengkapi Perabotan : Unfurnished Sertifikat : Lainnya Daya Listrik : 2200 Watt Kamar Tidur : 3/1 Kamar Mandi : 2/1 Luas Bangunan : 92 m² Luas Tanah : 126 m² Jumlah Lantai : -
Kondisi Properti : Bagus Sekali Dilengkapi Perabotan : Unfurnished Sertifikat : SHM - Sertifikat Hak Milik Daya Listrik : 6600 Watt Saluran Telepon : 1 Garasi : 3 Kamar Tidur : 4/1 Kamar Mandi : 3/1 Luas Bangunan : 300 m² Luas Tanah : 228 m² Jumlah Lantai : 2.5 ";

preg_match_all("/Luas Bangunan : [0-9]+/",$string,$out);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);


$keywords = preg_split("/Luas Bangunan : [0-9]+/" ,$string );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($keywords);
```

Comment: Hy Kanishka Panamaldeniya Thanks you help me and problem resolved

Comment: @badruz HI if my solution worked for you , please mark my answer as the correct solution , so the future users can see that easily and use it :)